# jQueryUI Sortable + Draggable and fixed position with overflow auto - can't drag items into sortable

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to design page where are two panels and one center content.
Like this:

```
<section>
    <div class="left">...</div>
    <div class="center">...</div>
    <div class="right">...</div>
</section>

jQuery('#left li').draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".EditingFormCategoryFields",
    helper: "clone",
});
jQuery('#center').sortable();
```

Left panel is source of items. Center panel is target for items.
There is problem with overflow. I need overflow: auto, because it could contain long content.

If you try this http://jsfiddle.net/NfQuk/3/ you will see that you couldn't drag items from left panel to center.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the overflow, but the fact that the draggable items are taking the 'left' div as container and thus cannot be dragged outside of it. Try setting the `containment` property to your section element.

Comment: this doesn't help. It helps me if I replace all "absolute" with "fixed" in jquery.ui.js file but it is not clean solution. This is a little bit workaround.